# Two related questions about iPhone autorotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

1) Is it possible to change the speed of autorotation on the iPhone?

2) Is it possible to time an animation to take place during the autorotation animation? I would like to resize a photo while rotation is occuring, rather than when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) not that I know of

2) Yes, see this method:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW53

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question, I haven't used this but check it out:

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration = [NSTimeInterval ...];

See docs for UIApplication. The problem is that I don't know that this actually rotates the rest of your views. You may, however, be able to rotate the window's coordinate system around "manually" using UIWindow and [UIView beginAnimations ...] in order to recreate the whole effect.

Please post sample code somewhere if you get it working!

Comment: UIApplication.statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration is read only.